# How to join items of type T and lists of type T in order?

Tags: c#

Many places in one project I have to declare a

```
var list = new List<T>();
```

and then add instances or lists of instances of a generic type, while keeping the order they are added. This ends up looking something like this:

```
list.AddRange(listOfinstances);
list.Add(instance);
list.Add(secondInstance);
list.Add(thirdInstance);
list.AddRange(secondListOfInstances);
```

Does there exist a neater helper or extension method I could use to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate the problem a bit more, or what you're looking for?

Comment: `list.Add(secondListOfInstances);` actually means `list.AddRange(secondListOfInstances);` ?

Comment: Perhaps some pseudocode of the kind of syntax you'd like to use instead might be helpful? I'm very confused as to what you want since I'm not sure how the code you have could be made any neater in my subjective view...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i got your issue, but can you do

```
var listOfinstances2 = new[]{ instance, secondInstance, thirdInstance, ... };
list.AddRange(listOfinstances);
list.AddRange(listOfinstances2);
```

Otherwise i don't know what kind of extension method you are thinking of. There is no inherent order, how should C# know that `secondInstance` is the second object?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind box and unbox (performance hit) then you can make your own extension method for that :

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static List<T> AddElements<T>(this List<T> list, params object[] args)
    {            
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            if (args[i] is T[]) { list.AddRange(args[i] as T[]); continue; }
            list.Add((T)args[i]);
        }
        return list;
    }
}

class Class12
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int n = 4; int n2 = 8;
        int[] ns = { 5, 6, 7 };
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };

        numbers = numbers.AddElements(n, ns, n2);

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(numbers[i] + "  "); 
        }


        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Output : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8